# Google Play Third-Party Referrals (UTM Source and Campaign) on the Beta Dashboard - Does it need Google Analytics SDK installed in my App or not?

Tags: google-analytics, google-play, utm-tracking

I have been trying to determine if, in order to see the the UTM Source and UTM Campaign in the new Google Play Dashboard, I need to have Google Analytics SDK installed in my app or not. I cannot seem to find with certainty if this is the case or not.

I have contacted Google Play Devs to check if I need to install anything in order to the the utm_source and utm_campaign tracked, and he categorically told me that no, there is no need.

So I did a test and tried in one app using the utm_source and utm_campaign tags. After 28 installs with the link generated [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#google-play-url-builder) all I got was 28 third-party referrals in the category "Other" and not the word I chose.

I also checked another app that I never created the link containing the UTM tags, but it shows the Third-Party and "Other".

So, really, I want to know what are the requirements to have a campaign tracked using UTM tags (utm_source & utm_campaign) because Google Play Devs tell me one thing, the documentation says another and the form to generate the link is under Google Analytics. So really confusing.

So the question is "In Google Play Dashboard (new beta) what is the requirements to track the UTM Tags in the conversion analysis?"

Comment: Hi, I have the exact same question, how did you solve this?

Comment: Hello @sudokai I still haven't solve this. All of my tests are resulting in "other" so far. Cannot say if the link is wrong, cannot say if the requirements are wrong or if I haven't reached the minimum "hits" in order to see the campaign or source.

Comment: Is this issue solved?

Comment: I have the same problem, all campaigns showing as "Other". Has anybody found out how to solve this?

Comment: has anyone resolved this issue yet? thank you!